# Value of $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{n}{(n+1)!}$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series, exponential-function

I am trying to show that the value of $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{n}{(n+1)!}$ is $1$. Leveraging the Taylor series of $e^{x}$ we know that,

$$e^x = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!} =  1 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!}$$

Now differentiate both sides with respect to $x$ we get,

$$e^x = 0+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n \cdot x^{(n-1)}}{n!} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n \cdot x^{(n-1)}}{n!}$$

Now we multiply numerator and denominator by $(n+1)$

$$e^x= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n \cdot x^{(n-1)}}{n!} \cdot \frac{n+1}{n+1}$$

thus,

$$e^x= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n \cdot x^{(n-1)}}{(n+1)!} \cdot {(n+1)} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n^2 \cdot x^{(n-1)}}{(n+1)!}+ \underbrace{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n \cdot x^{(n-1)}}{(n+1)!}}_\text{The expression we want, i.e, x=1}$$

$$ \implies \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n \cdot x^{(n-1)}}{(n+1)!} = e^x - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n^2 \cdot x^{(n-1)}}{(n+1)!} \tag1$$

Let $x=1$ then $(1)$ becomes,

$$  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n}{(n+1)!} = e - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n^2}{(n+1)!} $$

I expect $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n^2}{(n+1)!} = e - 1$, but I don't see how. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Hint: $n = n + 1 - 1$.

Comment: The operation $x^n\mapsto (n-k)x^{n-k-1}$ can be achieved by dividing by $x^{k}$ then differentiating. Here $\sum_{n>1} \frac{n-1}{n!}x^{n-2}=\frac{d}{dx}x^{-1}\sum_{n>1} \frac{1}{n!}x^{n}=\frac{d}{dx}x^{-1}(e^x-x-1)$ work out the derivative, and set $x=1$.

Comment: \begin{align*}
e^x &= 0+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n \cdot x^{(n-1)}}{n!} \\ 
  &= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n \cdot x^{(n-1)}}{n!} \\
  &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(n + 1) \cdot x^{(n-1)}}{(n+1)!} \\
  &= x^{-1} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(n + 1) \cdot x^{(n-1)}}{(n+1)!} \\
  &= x^{-1} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n \cdot x^{(n-1)}}{(n+1)!} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1 \cdot x^{(n-1)}}{(n+1)!}
\end{align*}

Comment: Let $x=1$
\begin{align*}
e^1 &= 1 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n}{(n+1)!} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(n + 1)!} \\
  &= 1 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n}{(n+1)!} + \left[ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(n)!} - 2 \right] \\
  &= 1 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n}{(n+1)!} + e - 2 \\
\end{align*}